# Shape placement using wildcard matching

Tags: orchardcms

Using Orcahrd CMS 1.3 is it possible to change the placement of a shape using multiple wildcards, or something similar?  For example, I would like to have the following placement.info file for my new module.

```
<Match Path="/products/*/purchase/*">

</Match>
```

Using the following route "/products/{category}/purchase I want to alter the placement of some shapes regardless of the category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. But you can reach similar results using a shape table provider, because from there you can write arbitrary code.